# Sap Cloud SDK - Create BP with custom field

Tags: sdk, cloud, field, s4hana

I have added the custom field (for example custom1) to SAP S/4 BUT000 table. I try to create a BP with this custom field by using cloud SDK. The field is added to properties _custom fields. When I execute the request builder there is error return "Property custom1 is invalid". Do I have to add the custom1 to the view A_BusinessPartner? Thank you.

Comment: how do you added that field? how do you execute your request? give the code

Comment: I have solved the issue. I used this Fiori app https://blogs.sap.com/2017/07/03/add-custom-fields-to-sap-s4hana-business-partner-odata-api-entities/ to add the custom field then use Sap cloud SDK to modify the custom field via Cloud App. Many thanks

Comment: So give you solution, please, so it helps all